# Python fakeldap library

Tags: python, unit-testing, ldap

I'm looking for a "fake LDAP" library for testing tasks. Anyone have some suggestions or experiences?

I found this https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fakeldap/0.5.1 and I tried it, but is not working for me and I think it is discontinued.